# Specifying pointcut in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am familiar with Spring AOP, although not having much hands on experience on that.

My question is, if I want to have some AOP functionality for some methods of a class, not all, then can it be possible with single pointcut. Say, I have four methods **save1,save2,get1 and get2** in my class and I want to apply AOP on **save1 and save2** only, then in that case how can I create a single pointcut for that? How will my pointcut expression looks like? OR Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it(with wildcard expression, with aspectJ annotation, ..)
i will give an example with aspectJ

```
class MyClass{
          @MyPoint 
          public void save1(){
          }  

          @MyPoint
          public void save2(){
          }  

          public void save3(){
          }  

          public void save4(){
          }  

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyPoint {
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(com.xyz.MyPoint)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //do here what u want
    }

}
```

So you are all set, as long as you marked `@Mypoint` annotation, spring will call before aspect for this method, make sure spring is managing this method and object, not you. include aspectJ in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a pointcut expression to select the methods with to apply your advice.

See 7.2.3 Declaring a pointcut in [the Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) and use the execution joinpoint designator to select the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Having a pointcut expression like so should do the trick

```
**execution(* save*(..))**
```

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` and `and` with pointcut expressions:

```
execution(* my.Class.myMethod(..)) or execution(* my.Class.myOtherMethod(..))
```

Comment: Actally or didn't work, had to use || instead                                                                     
execution(* my.Class.myMethod(..)) || execution(* my.Class.myOtherMethod(..))